# Reverse Bias PN-Junction/Diodes

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

In a revesed bias PN-Junction/Diode, the electrons are attracted to the positive terminal from the external power supply while the holes are attracted to the negative terminal, incrasing the depletion region and thus preventing current flow. No difficulty there. My question is:

Take the p-side. It's conneted to the negative terminal from the battery, which attracts the holes (which are the lack of an electron). Then why don't the electrons from the negative side of the battery fill all the existing holes from the p-side, completing the octec rule, getting stuck to the lattice and permanently extinguishing all mobile charges (holes) in the p-region even after the external power source is turned off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Holes are not traps. Traps are immobile crystal defects that behave somewhat like what you imagine: drop an electron into a trap and it'll be stuck there for a short time (but not permanently). Holes are free to move, and the ohmic contact on the P end of a diode can create them as needed to match the potential of the crystal to the attached wire.

When you attach the negative battery terminal of the battery to the P side of a diode, it attracts some of the holes away from the junction making the depletion region wider. Depleted P-type semiconductor has a negative space charge (no holes to neutralize the extra valence charge), and you may think of that charge (along with the positive charge on the N side) as providing the field across the junction that balances the EMF of the battery. Detach the battery, connect the P and N sides of the diode together, and holes will flow back into the portion of the semiconductor that the battery depleted.